# iPhone 6s plus black and didnt have visual after screen replacement

Tags: iphone

this lately, i just accidentally broke and smashed my iphone and the screen was shattered, the ribbon of home button and the lcd also the 3g front camera was snapped. I decide to buy some replacement for these part and install them. After i get the parts and firstly i check for the iphone whether it still alive or not, i connect the iphone to the itunes and i found the iTunes detected my device but i cant access because it need to unlock first. so i tried to connect the LCD and i found that the LCD was black and didnt have any visual. i wonder is it damage from the new LCD it self or it was from the logic board it self? i was worried if i get the new lcd and it still didnt work. i also try to put my simcard and the iphone still can receive the call, is this really means that my phone still can be saved? (plus, when i on the phone and connect to the itunes without lcd screen, i found the panel on upper side which sit directly under the lcd socket was little bit warm, is it normal?)

Answer (score 1):

Here is our overall answer how to revive a phone that is frozen and you can’t operate the screen, can’t turn it off or can’t turn it on.

- [iPhone 7 is frozen and I can't turn it off](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/355306/iphone-7-is-frozen-and-i-cant-turn-it-off)

Once you’ve exhausted these steps, you will need to repair the part that’s not working and if you’ve repaired the screen already, it might be a more costly piece or a cable that’s failed.